# load works on local path, require doesn't

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.2

loadee.rb

```
puts '> This is the second file.'
```

loaddemo.rb

```
puts 'This is the first (master) program file.'
load 'loadee.rb'
puts 'And back again to the first file.'
```

When I run `"ruby loaddemo.rb"`, This works fine. Both files are in the same directory, and that's the directory I run from.

But if I change the load to a require, and with or without the extension I get:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load
 -- loadee.rb (LoadError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from loaddemo.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

My question is of course, why isn't require working in this case?  It should, right?  Do load and require use different paths?

Ruby version 1.9.2

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you provide just a filename to `require`, it will only look in the predefined `$LOAD_PATH` directories. However, if you provide a path with your filename, it should work:

```
puts 'This is the first (master) program file.'
require './loadee.rb'
puts 'And back again to the first file.'
```

You could also add your project's folder to the load path instead:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)
puts 'This is the first (master) program file.'
require 'loadee.rb'
puts 'And back again to the first file.'
```

And last, you could just use `require_relative` instead:

```
puts 'This is the first (master) program file.'
require_relative 'loadee.rb'
puts 'And back again to the first file.'
```

Comment: So why does load work without the path?  Does it use a different path variable?

Comment: This is actually listed as a bug for ruby right now. 1.9 removed the "current directory" from the load path when using `require`, but not for `load`. http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/2710

Comment: Also, keep in mind that every time you use `load`, it evaluates the entire file, whereas using `require` only evaluates the file the first time you require it.

Answer (score 7):

Providing a path with the filename seemed not to work for me, and I didn't want to cram a bunch of paths into my `$LOAD_PATH`.

Checking out the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative), I found `require_relative`.

```
require_relative 'loadee'
```

Works in both `1.9.2` and `2.1.2`.

The [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require) indicates that `require` is not intended to search relative paths at all, and neither is `load`.